# Two different users accessing same Wordpress page but have different views of a d3 object in that page

Tags: wordpress, d3.js

This is a question regarding data driven documents (d3 for short) and Wordpress:

I wonder if it would be possible to create a WordPress page that contains a d3 object (say a bar chart) and allow two different users of the same WordPress site to access that particular page, but view the d3 object modulo their own data. I thought for some workarounds like creating for each user a dedicated page and link the page with his/her data but that would scale to a nightmare if you have a lot of users and a lot of such pages for each one of them. I wish you could give me some ideas or feedback. Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "their own data"? Do the users provide the data? Is it tied to their account? What are you trying to visualize?

Comment: @jshanley: Yes, users - theoretically - could provide their own data, e.g. Users (or the admin on their behalf and upon their request) alter in a way the .csv files uploaded in Wordpress that contains their data, used to draw the d3 object. For example for user A the data might be (1,2,2,1,2) while for user B might be (1,2,3,2,2), and both users A and B wish to access the same page that contains the d3 object that uses these two different datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'll have to modify the Wordpress template of that page to 'send' the user-id (or name) to the webpage. For that see [Send wordpress $current_user->ID from php file to external Javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990685/send-wordpress-current-user-id-from-php-file-to-external-javascript-file). You can then use that user-id to load the correct csv-file which can then be used generate your graph.